# Rename endpoint in AWS Api Gateway and keep backward compatibility

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-api-gateway

I have an API deployed on AWS with API Gateway, and everything is in the plural form, except one route, `/user`, like:

`https://0123456abcde.execute-api.pluto-1.amazonaws.com/production/user/settings`.

- How can I rename it to `/users`
- And create a redirection from `/user` to `/users`

I will delete later the redirection, but I need to wait that the latest release of my App on the Stores is deployed for 100% of end users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not perform a redirection, you may lose authentication headers and if its a post request the body contents will not be redirected.

You have 3 choices:

- Keep the 2 as they are now, then once the app has been fully updated in the future then remove it.
- Replace the `/user` endpoint to forward to a Lambda function that will perform the request against the API Gateway endpoint again.
- Replace the `/user` endpoint to use `http_proxy` to forward the request back to the same API Gateway endpoint.

Comment: I will try to create a copy. It seems faster and safer right now.

Comment: Sure, it just makes any rollbacks easier too :) Best of luck

Comment: OK so I've chosen to go for choice number 1!